# Akka-http how to log server error responses?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a http server built with scala and akka-http. Is there a way I can log the error responses sent to clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the documentation [LogResult Directive](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logResult.html#logresult)

Here you can find the same snipped of code shown in the documentation:

```
// different possibilities of using logResponse

// The first alternatives use an implicitly available LoggingContext for logging
// marks with "get-user", log with debug level, HttpResponse.toString
DebuggingDirectives.logResult("get-user")

// marks with "get-user", log with info level, HttpResponse.toString
DebuggingDirectives.logResult(("get-user", Logging.InfoLevel))

// logs just the response status at debug level
def responseStatus(res: RouteResult): String = res match {
  case RouteResult.Complete(x)          => x.status.toString
  case RouteResult.Rejected(rejections) => "Rejected: " + rejections.mkString(", ")
}
DebuggingDirectives.logResult(responseStatus _)

// logs just the response status at info level
def responseStatusAsInfo(res: RouteResult): LogEntry = LogEntry(responseStatus(res), Logging.InfoLevel)
DebuggingDirectives.logResult(responseStatusAsInfo _)

// This one doesn't use the implicit LoggingContext but uses `println` for logging
def printResponseStatus(res: RouteResult): Unit = println(responseStatus(res))
val logResultPrintln = DebuggingDirectives.logResult(LoggingMagnet(_ => printResponseStatus))

// tests:
Get("/") ~> logResultPrintln(complete("logged")) ~> check {
  responseAs[String] shouldEqual "logged"
}
```